# How do I check if a set of commands are executed on startup?

Tags: command-line, startup, display-resolution, xrandr, .desktop

I'm in the process of creating a GUI-frontend to `xrandr`, and I need some commands to be executed on startup.

I'm using a `.desktop` file placed in `~/.config/autostart`.

I can't tell if this will work, since `xrandr` doesn't work with my setup - I know things are working as they are meant to be; it's just my system doesn't support it - I'll just a get a bunch of xrandr errors. Which also means that I'll get errors on startup and no noticable change.

Is there some way of finding out whether the commands have been executed?

Comment: Does this `.desktop`file run a script? If yes, how about putting some lines into your script where you monitor if it has run like `echo "script has run" > ~/script.log`?

Comment: Great idea! It does run a script, so that would work fine. Do you want to write that as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Sure thing let me type that quick :)

Comment: have a look at my revised answer.

Comment: @Videonauth Thanks a load. That's really useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your auto started `.desktop` file is a script you simply can put a control echo into the script like following example:

```
# if yyou want only data saved for one run

echo "Script has run on $(date)" > ~/script.log

# if you want a continous log output append

if [ -e ~/script-log ]
    then
        echo "Script has run on $(date)" >> ~/script.log
else
        touch ~/script.log
        echo "Script has run on $(date)" >> ~/script.log
fi
```

This way you even can output some variable data you might want for controling this way. Just make sure your final result is printed after all commands in the script so you know the script has run through.

If you want to exactly know if your commands in your script have failed you as well can do:

```
# do this at start of your script

if [ -e ~/script-error.log ]
    then
        # we do nothing
else
        touch ~/script-error.log
fi

# then within your script (I use as example here cd /root just to demonstrate)
# you can do this with nearly all commands

cd /root 2>> ~/script-error.log
```

This would fetch only if one of your commands would throw an error. Sure not applicable everywhere but sill better as having no output at all.

Explanation of the piping:

```
# single piping symbol (overwrite the existing file and creates one if not existant)
>               # pipes all output 
1>              # pipes only success messages
2>              # pipes only error messages

# double piping symbol (append to an existing file and fail if file does not exist)
>>              # pipes all output
1>>             # pipes only success messages
2>>             # pipes only error messages
```

Want to know more about bash scripting in depth here two links:

[Bash Guide for Beginners - Machtelt Garrels - 2008](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html)
[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide - Mendel Cooper - 2014](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html)

Comment: It depends on *how* you implement this in your script if it is a reliable way or not. It could very well be the script fails completely while the log shows a success :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm how could that happen?

Comment: @DevRobot Example you use the echo at the start of your script and then it bugs out. So rather use it at the end of the script.

Comment: @DevRobot if a script has unconditional commands, the next one will be executed no matter if the previous command was sucessfull or not.

Comment: @Videonauth exactly, which brings me to the idea that it might not be a dupe of the linked one. That is about backround scripts/processes. Is this one?

Comment: @DevRobot another solution is comming aswell. Editing.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I think it's a background process. The linked question says "As result, autostart command was silently failing." - could be the same thing here, apart from the fact that I'm using `xrandr`

Comment: @DevRobot Ah, luckily.

Comment: @DevRobot edited my answer to contain more info on how to fetch eventual errors.

Comment: What's the `2` before the `>` pipe for?

Comment: @DevRobot it filters only the error messages `>` does all `2>` does only errorsmessages `1>` does only messages which are good runs

Comment: @DevRobot this works aswell with appending `>>` pipe just make sure the files exist before by `touch filename`. i guess appending would be better for you so you get a constant log which you even can rotate. going to incorporate this all into my answer now.

Comment: @JacobVlijm don't you think the question should be reopened? The answer given is way different to the answer you've given in the linked question

Comment: @DevRobot As a general rule, not the answer defines the dupe, but the question. The key is if you meant to ask about *processes* or a single run script from a to z.